# Render latex preview of equation like in latex export (with preceeding/trailing newline)

Tags: latex, fragment, org-mode, preview

I am struggling with latex preview in org-mode.

Basically I am trying to preview someting like this:

```
* Section2
\[
X=\frac{1}{2}
\]
```

In general this works, but the overlay image does not contain preceeding/trailing newlines before/after the math environment. Full latex export however would introduce these newlines.

In addition I use the following options in my header in order to keep the original org spacing in my pdf:

```
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
```

The combination of employed header and fragment mismatch, however, either messes up readability of my org file, i.e. the preview fragment is put too close to the heading "Section2". Or, when I insert a new line in org, in order to increase the readability, the spacing of my latex export looks strange, due to this extra line plus the preceeding/trailing lines from the math environment.

Can someone give me a hint how I can convince org-mode to create the fragment in accordance with the full latex export?

I am using emacs 26.3 with miktex.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You cannot: the fragment is compiled on its own so there is no context that would tell LaTeX what the full export would look like. Have you tried not using the option and then introducing extra space in the Org mode file between the headline and the fragment?

Comment: BTW, any white space that is added to the tex file with the option does not survive the typesetting to PDF: LaTeX ignores extra white space in its input.